# Exposing goto labels to symbol table

Tags: c++, c, gcc, symbols, goto

I want to know whether it is possible to expose goto label within a function to symbol table from C/C++

For instance, I want to make *ret* label of the following snippet appeared from the symbol table and can be referred using standard APIs such as dlsym().

Thanks for your help in advance!

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main () {
  void *ret_p = &&ret;
  printf("ret: %p\n", ret_p);
  goto *ret_p;

  return 1;

  ret:
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Simply not possible (and your code isn’t standard C++ and, AFAIK, neither is it standard C – but you probably know that).

Comment: You could use an inline asm to add whatever code the assembler expects to indicate a symbol. (Btw, &&ret is a gcc extension I think, you may want to add a gcc tag)

Comment: @KonradRudolph Yes you're right Konrad, computed goto is not part of standard. However I'm looking for a solution that works for gcc (or clang).

Comment: I'm sure one could edit symbol table after compilation and add a "symbol" that points to an offset in a known function, then read that address and jmp to it and hope registers and memory states won't cause CPU to blow up in smokes right away...

Comment: **Aaaaaaarrgh!!!** If `goto` is evil, what's this then?? The misgiving of the apocalyptical beast?!?

Comment: @Eugene Actually I'm trying to find/identify offset from the function address to a target label. If I can I find a way to do it in a reliable manner, I think this problem is solved.

Comment: @g-makulik I still think that using goto statement is not a good practice. however, I'm stuck in a situation where I can't avoid using it.

Comment: This is certainly an interesting question but I’m sceptical of your claim that you’re “stuck in a situation where [you] can’t avoid using it”. There *must* be a way around that; in any case it’d be interesting to know more about your situation.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to [Marc Glisse](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1918193/marc-glisse)'s comment which is about using inline asm that specifies label, I could come up with a workaround for the question. The following example code snippet shows how I solved the problem.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main () {
  void *ret_p = &&ret;
  printf("ret: %p\n", ret_p);
  goto *ret_p;

  return 1;

  ret:
  asm("RET:")

  return 0;
}
```

This will add a symbol table entry as follows.

```
jikk@sos15-32:~$ gcc  -Wl,--export-dynamic t.c  -ldl
jikk@sos15-32:~$ readelf -s a.out 

39: 08048620     0 FUNC    LOCAL  DEFAULT   13 __do_global_ctors_aux
40: 00000000     0 FILE    LOCAL  DEFAULT  ABS t.c
41: 0804858a     0 NOTYPE  LOCAL  DEFAULT   13 RET
42: 08048612     0 FUNC    LOCAL  DEFAULT   13 __i686.get_pc_thunk.bx
43: 08049f20     0 OBJECT  LOCAL  DEFAULT   19 __DTOR_END__

jikk@sos15-32:~$ ./a.out
ret: 0x804858a
```

I'll further test this workaround the verify whether this produces any unexpected side effects.

Thanks